# Can I leave my car by a Jewish secular mechanic if there's a possibility that he'll do work on it on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, business

If it's Friday or close to Friday, am I allowed to leave my car at a Jewish secular mechanic to do a job at a set rate with the possibility that he'll work on it on Shabbat?

Would it help if I asked him to refrain working on it on Shabbat?

The question [May a halachically 'Jewish' Atheist work as a 'Shabbat goy'?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48020/may-a-halachically-jewish-atheist-work-as-a-shabbat-goy) is related but different from what I am asking. The first difference is that you are specifically hiring the athiest to work for you on shabbat - here it's simply a possiblity that the mechanic will do the job on Shabbat but not a necessity. Second difference the mechanic is not necessarily an athiest but simply non-religious (tinok shenishba or what have you...).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53742/can-a-gentile-shovel-plow-snow-from-your-driveway-on-shabbat-if-he-has-been-pa?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48020 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23519 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31464