# Is there a problem with eating food on Shabbat cooked by someone who doesn't keep it?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food

To what degree is this a problem if: 1) your level of kashrut is the same as this person who's cooking and 2) They do not cook on Shabbat?

Edit: To clarify, this didn't seem like a problem to me until someone told me it's not allowed. Now I'm looking for sources on that.

Comment: If they do not cook on Shabbat then what's the connection to your eating it on Shabbat?

Comment: I have no clue. That's why I'm looking for a source.

Comment: I'm still not sure I'm getting your case exactly, but maybe the concern is someone who doesn't keep Shabbos is in some ways like a gentile so maybe bishul akum applies to all their cooking?

Comment: In that case, would turning on the oven or stove for them be good enough?

Comment: If the person who cooked it is Jewish, I believe that you may never eat that food.

Comment: @ReotheNew It's very likely forbidden for reasons of kashrus. For reasons of Shabbos, see here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44693/can-you-derive-benefit-from-another-jews-melacha-if-it-happened-a-long-time-ago